# Toolbar в AppBarLayout съезжает в бок

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Добавил `Toolbar`, во время скролинга он уходит в верх, проблема в том что сам `Toolbar` смещён немного в право. Подскажите как это исправить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.Menu_list.Menu_list_Tasks.Fragment_Menu_list_Tasks">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        app:elevation="0dp">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/back"
                style="@style/ImageButton_1"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextView_14"
                android:text="@string/any" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/quick_menu"
                style="@style/ImageButton_1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_quick_menu" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        <View style="@style/View_1" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <View style="@style/View_3" />

            <LinearLayout style="@style/LinearLayout_0">

                <View style="@style/View_1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="96dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_prapor"
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:src="@mipmap/w1" />

                    <View style="@style/View_2" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txv_prapor"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/traders1"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@drawable/text"
                        android:textSize="24sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View style="@style/View_1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Styles

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_1</item> <!--Меняем только этот-->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_0</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_6</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320632/3212712

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте [вот такие](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32320632/3212712) атрибуты в разметку Toolbar.

```
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
```

А вообще, если вы целиком изменили внешний вид Toolbar, то он вам и не нужен совсем, его можно просто удалить.